# Magnitude of torque due to weight in a simple pendulum

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, angle, cross-product

Suppose we have a simple pendulum as shown in figure

[image].

In this frame, suppose we fix $\theta$ as positive if rotation is at right of axis of symmetry (as depicted in figure) and negative if rotation is at the left of it.

As we know, "magnitude of the torque vector due to weight" is proportional to the sine of the angle between vector distance of the mass from rotation axis and the vector weight.

My question is: this angle between the vectors should be $\theta$. But then we would have:

- $|T| = |l|\cdot|p|\cdot \sin(\theta)$,   if $\theta >0$
- $|T| = |l|\cdot|p|\cdot \sin(\theta)$,   if $\theta <0$

Is it correct to pose $|\sin(\theta)|$ if $\theta <0$?

If not so, magnitude couldn't be positive as it must be. I ask this because in definition of magnitude of cross product it never mentions the fact that angle between the two vectors could be negative, but must be always between $0$ and $\pi$, and never tells we should pose the absolute value of sine if required, as in this case we seem legitimate to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

[image]

and[image]

(Sorry, I just flipped it).

The torque due to weight, *about the point of suspension*, is given as $$\vec \tau = \vec l\times \vec w$$ where $\vec w$ is the weight.

Now, by the right-hand thumb rule, you’ll notice that the torques in both the cases point in *opposite directions* wrt each other: into the screen in the first case, out of the plane of the screen in the second.

If you decide to measure angles with the vertical line through the point of suspension as the reference line, then you’ll get a negative sign in the second case, which will just simply refer to the fact that the torque is in the opposite direction to that when all quantities were assumed positive, i.e. in the first case.

In both cases, the magnitude of the torque remains the same, i.e. $$|\vec \tau|=|\vec l||\vec w||sin \theta|.$$ regardless of whether $\theta$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok i understood, just two points: 

1. But in this case we are not talking about right hand rule to determine the sense in which torque vector points, just the magnitude, right?
2. Allright so even though in textbooks the say that magnitude of torque is just proportional to sine of angle between the two vectors without magnitude and that it must be between 0 and pi, here we can generalize and say: whicever teta is (positive or negative) we are ok in both case if we take |sin(teta)| isn't it?

Comment: 1.Magnitude of something in a physics sense of things is always positive. 2. I’d rather write it as $\sin |\theta|$.

Comment: Ok, good, i've never seen neither |sin(teta)| nor sin(|teta|) in textbooks definitions of magnitude of cross product; it's very strange since it would make perfectly sense as you explained. Thank you again!

Comment: i constructed a proof that putting |sen(teta)| is indeed correct and that angle teta can be any measure (positive, null or negative) for the angle between two vectors. If interested tell me.